# How do I pass an Angular object to a Javascript function in a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Google chrome extension that "scrapes" the DOM of a particular website for objects and processes them in javascript functions.

Currently I am using the chrome.tabs.query API to perform operations in the background page. I was able to pull data out of the url with

```
    chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(url);
    var s = url.split('?')[1];
    var installation = s.split('&')[0];
    full_url = 'http://domain.com/' + url;
    window.open(full_url, '_blank');
});
```

But now I am trying to pass an Angular object from the DOM of the page to a similar function:

```
    chrome.tabs.query({ "active": true, "lastFocusedWindow": true }, function (tabs) {
        var dom_el = this.document.querySelector('[ng-controller="chartNewController"]');
        var ng_el = this.angular.element(dom_el);
        var ng_el_scope = this.ng_el.scope();
        var address = this.ng_el_scope.fullAddress;
    console.log(address);
});
```

And I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
>       at null.callback

I am not sure I am going about the is the most efficient way  so my question is what is the most optimal way to "scrape" Angular objects in the DOM of a background HTML page in regards to building a chrome extension?

Comment: You have to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors for the following line:

```
var dom_el = this.document.querySelector('[ng-controller="chartNewController"]');
```

1. `this` means the callback, there is no property `document` for `this` object
2. Event if you directly use `document.querySelector...`, you would be still unable to get the element, since when you call this line in background page, `document` points to background page document rather than the web page.

One suggestion would be using [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to get the value, you would need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and establish communication between it and background page.

Background page:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ "active": true, "lastFocusedWindow": true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: 'get'}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.address);
    });
});
```

Content script (**You would need to retrieve the correct angular object, that depends on your web page, I can't help with that**):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.action === 'get') {
        var dom_el = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="chartNewController"]');
        // Ensure retrieving the correct angular object (The previous this object), that depends on your web page environment.
        var ng_el = angular.element(dom_el);
        var ng_el_scope = ng_el.scope();
        var address = ng_el_scope.fullAddress;
        sendResponse({ address: address });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For those with a similar question, I found that you can also inject raw code into the webpage using

```
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'console.log('Hello World')'
    });
```

I came across this solution when I became stuck at a chrome extension file not found error. I believe there is a limitation of what code can actually be injected into the page but I am not 100% sure the exact limitations.